# C++ access violation in opengl / glsl / sdl code

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, access-violation

I am following some tutorials online regarding the GLSL. I have been implementing the code into my current program. It compiles just fine, but when I debug it, I get an access violation:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in Game Engine v0.2a.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in Game Engine v0.2a.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
```

I am not sure why. Here is the line it is pointing to:

```
GLuint v,f,f2,p,ge;
int gw = RESOLUTION_X;
int gh = RESOLUTION_Y;

void setShaders() 
{
    char *vs = NULL, *fs = NULL, *fs2 = NULL, *gs = NULL;

    v  = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER); //<-- this line
    f  = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    ge = glCreateShader(GL_GEOMETRY_SHADER_EXT);

...
```

Do I need to provide any additional code? I'm just not sure what is being done wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to call [`SDL_Init`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlinit.html)? Or maybe calling this function from multiple threads?

Comment: +1; this hypothesis is reinforced by the fact that the exception is thrown when calling address 0x00; possibly due to `glCreateShader` being a NULL-initialized pointer-to-function.

Comment: This is in fact true. I was calling glew init before sdl init.

Comment: I have never used SDL in my life, never even tried, but saw tons of questions about SDL crashes like this before, and every time it turned out to be `SDL_Init`. So there we go :)

Comment: Ha, good thing I decided to note that it was SDL in the title. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that glCreateShader is a NULL pointer to function. This is a function that not all drivers support, so you should be using some kind of GL extension wrapper, such as the excellent GLEW.

And before using an extension you should check that it is supported by the current implementation: in your case it is a GL2.0 function so: `if (GLEW_VERSION_2_0) ...`.